# WSL install Ubuntu get 0x80370114

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux, windows-11

I tried to install Linux using WSL. When I launch Ubuntu, it tells me:

```
WslRegisterDistribution failed with error: 0x80370114
```

My Windows is Windows 11 Home (Chinese), so Hyper-V is not available. `wsl.exe -v` gives me following info:

```
C:\Users\atlan>wsl.exe -v
WSL version: 1.1.6.0
Kernel version: 5.15.90.1
WSLg version: 1.0.50
MSRDC version: 1.2.3770
Direct3D version: 1.608.2-61064218
DXCore version: 10.0.25131.1002-220531-1700.rs-onecore-base2-hyp
Windows version: 10.0.22621.1413
```

I've enabled WSL and Virtual Machine in Windows Features. But nothing changed.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: How you looked up that WSL Microsoft error? error: 0x80370114 That is from the WSL not Ubuntu.

Comment: @David Yes I've tried all I could found on Google. But they are not effective. I wonder if Windows Professional Edition would work?

Comment: Did you go to Microsoft support and search the error message?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error when installing WSL and Ubuntu on Windows 11](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1447753/error-when-installing-wsl-and-ubuntu-on-windows-11)

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu!  What does `wsl -l -v` show?  Please [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1463280/edit) the question to include the output since it doesn't format well in comments.  Thanks!